# Dropdown Boxes cloned with JQuery don't retain the behaviour of the original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

What I am trying to do is clone 3 drop-down boxes and add them beneath the original set.

At the moment it works but the clones do not maintain the functionaility of the original set.

What the originals do is check the selected value of the first drop-down box in order to populate the drop-down lists for the other two.

Fiddle is below but adding the clones doesn't seem to work for some reason I can't figure out, it works on the page I am working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/pV6x5/6/

Thanks,

Martin

**UPDATE**

updated the fiddle, it was missing the `advancedsearch` div: http://jsfiddle.net/pV6x5/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery live to keep the event's bound to the new elements. With live it binds the event to all present and future elements where just defining a handler for change will only bind for the current elements (you can also just reattach the events every time you create an element but why do it when live takes care of it for you)

```
$tags.live("change",function(){ /* your stuff here */});
```

**UPDATE** Here is the change function and if block:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$tags = $("select[name='tags']");

$tags.live("change",function()
{
    $operands = $(this).parent().find("select[name='operands']");
    $values = $(this).parent().find("select[name='values']");
if ($(this).val() == "agent") 
{

$(this).parent().find("select[name='operands'] option").remove();

$("<option>=</option>").appendTo($operands);
$("<option>!=</option>").appendTo($operands);

$(this).parent().find("select[name='values'] option").remove();
$("<option>excel</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>msword</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>ppt</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>pdf</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>image</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>txt</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>html</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>csv</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>ooxml</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>flash</option>").appendTo($values);
$("<option>wmf</option>").appendTo($values);
}
```

Comment: durr I had a major syntax flaw when I attempted to cut and paste your tag object to the live function. This syntax is the correct one.

Comment: something about that doesn't look correct, why would you leave the .change() in there? Just replace it with the .live('change') bind. As a sidenote, I don't know if this was intended, but I like the idea of prefixing all jQuery object variable names with "$" it's a nice, easy way to delineate which ones are already jQuery objects.

Comment: thanks very much for your helpt but it's thrown up a strange bug: http://jsfiddle.net/pV6x5/9/

when you slect the option in the cloned drop-downs, the values drop-down (last one of the 3) in the original is what changes, instead of the relevant cloned one :S

Comment: I just noticed you are trying to clone and keep the same id. Id's need to be unique so before you insert the cloned element in. Also you should change the update code to find the sibling of this whose class is values by doing a $(this).parent().find(".values")

Comment: an example of that would be in the if($(this).val() == "agent"){ $(this).parent().find("select[name='operands'] option").remove();

Comment: thank you - I tried this but I don't think I've implemented your advice correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/pV6x5/13/

Comment: Your append stuff needs to change to this: $(this).parent().find("select[name='operands'] option").remove();
    
$(this).parent().find("select[name='operands']").append("<option>=</option>");
$(this).parent().find("select[name='operands']").append("<option>!=</option>")

Comment: another solution (rather than swapping it out everywhere) is to redefine $operands wihtin the change function to $operands = $(this).parent().find("select[name='operands']");

Comment: Thanks again - do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pV6x5/14/

Seems to break it unless I've not fully understood what you meant?

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle. I only set up the first part of the change function. http://jsfiddle.net/pV6x5/18/ But you *should* be able to follow it and use it for the others. Please read the jQuery API so you get an idea of what is going on. But feel free to ask if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use the .live() bind, so that it attaches the events to the objects made "in the future."
http://api.jquery.com/live/

So rather than .change() you need .live('change')